# Difference between Xamrin android, Xamrin iOS and Xamrine crossplatform project

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

What is the difference between xamarin android, xamarin ios and xamrin crossplatform project? xamarin android and xamrin ios are native? I thought we only make one single app on Xamarin that works on both ios and android.

p.s: just started to work with Xamarin.

Comment: https://www.xamarin.com/platform

Answer (score 1):

I will copy the info from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/)

Xamarin Android makes it possible for you to create native Android applications using the same UI controls as you would in Java, but with the flexibility and elegance of a modern language (C#).

Xamarin.iOS allows developers to create native iOS applications using the same UI controls that are available in Objective-C and Xcode, except with the flexibility and elegance of a modern language (C#).

And Xamarin Cross Platform, it's a little more complex to explain.
[image: Xamarin Forms]

As you can see in the image, with Xamarin Cross Platform, you can share a tremendous amount of code between your apps(iOS, Android, UWP, etc) and if you use Xamarin Forms you can share the UI (which is based in XAML and of course you can implement native things with Custom Renders).

You can view more about Xamarin in their developer web page:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/

Comment: Thank you! this answers my question @NestorDaniel

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to notice is when you use Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Droid you are dealing with the lifecycle and the UIs of iOS or Android. That means you need to have the knowledge of both platforms. If you are using Xamarin.Forms you will have another, more common, lifecycle and a common UI. So you don't have to know the platform specifics. (except you need a more complex app).

When i think of Xamarin.Forms i always ask myself "what have ios and android in common?" The answer would be for example "a label, a switch a listview etc." this things you will find as Controls in Xamarin.Forms. Things like SegmentedControl from iOS you will not find there, you have to write a CustomRenderer to use them!

To be clear, with Xamarin.Forms you can also use 100 percent of the platform specific API. For Rendering stuff you need a CustomRenderer as mentioned before and for platform specific things like the calendar you have to use the built in Xamarin DependencyService to handle both platforms in the common code.

No matter which way you choose all three ways result in a **native app**

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: Thanks for additional info. @Tomislav